# How to add dependencies to project's top-level build.gradle file?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying a sample code which implements **Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)** and that is provided by google itself, [**GCM Demo**](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#get-config).

I don't know how exactly I can add the dependencies

- List item
- Add the dependency to your project's top-level build.gradle:
- When I go to Project Structure > Modules > Add and then select Module Dependency then a pop up screen appears for no module found to depend on.
  If there is another way I can add the dependencies then a help would be appreciated.I have attached an image regarding the same.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As described in the [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#get-config).

Add the dependency to your project's top-level `build.gradle`: (just edit the file)

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
```

You should have somenthing like this:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Then add the plugin to your app-level `build.gradle` (just edit the file):

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

You should have somenthing like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
  //..
}
```

Finally add the dependency in your app-level `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0"
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit confused about these two gradle files. I have one in my app/platforms/android and another one in my app/platforms/android/CordovaLib. Now my question is, which one is project-level and which one app-level build.gradle? Can you please help me?

Comment: Working with ionic/Cordova, I would also like a clearer explanation how this translates.

Comment: Such a stupid configuration from Google and gradle. What's the usage of cascading build scripts if we need to define the dependency in the app-level and module-level build scripts? I have more than 10 modules, all dependent on `volley` to make HTTP requests. I would expect to add volley once in the top-level gradle script, and that be the end of it.

Comment: Agree with Saeed Neamati, this is not a good design from a maintenance perspective

Comment: is there a way to mention classpath in app-level build.gradle? searched quite a few links but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @SarthakMittal Yes. You can use the buildscript block inside the app-level build.gradle file.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yeah it worked, thanks! earlier I thought repository block need not be added :)