# How to manage common dependencies for multiple Android library projects?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm aware of this question: [How to add dependencies to project's top-level build.gradle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113337/how-to-add-dependencies-to-projects-top-level-build-gradle-file)

But it doesn't give the answer I need.

Lets say my android project has 3 library modules `A`, `B` and `C`.
And all three uses a common dependency say `D1` where `D1` is library like `Dagger`, `Room`, etc.

Now instead of adding `D1` to all three, I am thinking about adding `D1` to project level `build.gradle`.

I tried doing something like this but it gives error as:

`Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.15'
        implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16"
        kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.16"
        kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What is the correct way of adding dependencies in project level `build.gradle` ?

Here is the project link: https://github.com/cerberusv2px/android-modular

Answer (score 4):

Create a new module project called, e.g. `common-libs`, and put all your common dependencies into this project, open the `common-libs/build.gradle`.

change

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

To

```
api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

And then for all the upstream depending projects, just call

```
dependencies {
    ...
    api project(':common-libs')
}
```

See: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations

Comment: Could not find method api() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Do I need to add something like `apply-plugin` ?

Comment: I mean, you need to add this into your  `build.gradle` of your `D1` module, and remember to remove the one you tried in `allprojects{ ... }`.

Comment: no no. Sorry if i was not clear. But here D1 means dependencies libraries like dagger not my own custom module

Comment: ok, then you can create a new module project called, e.g. `common-libs`, and put all your common dependencies into this project, then for all the upstream depending projects, just call `api project(':common-libs')`.

Comment: Yes it works. One quick question. Replacing all `implementation` with `api` works correctly. But what to do in the case of `kapt` or `annotation-processor` ?

Comment: So far as I know, for annotation, it has no clean solution as `api`. Sad!

Comment: Best Answer, :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `subprojects` instead of `allprojects` as the main module is not configured with any build options.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Android Projects Built by Google itself, they usually create ExtraPropertiesExtension at the top level build.gradle file.

Doing so, you could create a global extension property to all gradle modules your project is using.

As a sample you could do something like this in your build.gradle:

```
ext.versions = [ 'dependencyVersion': 28 ]
```

and so in your module's build.gradle module, you culd reference to this attribute like so:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    implementation "com.some.dependency.you:use:${versions.dependencyVersion}"
}
```

Here's a link to Nick Butcher's App called Plaid:[Plaid](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid)

The same pattern is used with the Google IO and Android Dev Summit App, You could at them here:
[Android Dev Summit App 2018](https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/adssched)
[Google IO Schedule App 2018](https://github.com/google/iosched)

Answer (score 0):

Method that I use is

**Using separate gradle file for common things in each module and applying that gradle file in the module's gradle file,**

which I learned from [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/intro-to-app-modularization-42411e4c421e).

**Example :**

**common.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion Versions.TARGET_SDK
    buildToolsVersion Versions.BUILD_TOOLS


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion Versions.MIN_SDK
        targetSdkVersion Versions.TARGET_SDK
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation AndroidDeps.KOTLIN_STD_LIB
    implementation AndroidDeps.APP_COMPAT
    implementation AndroidDeps.CORE_KTX

    implementation ToolingDeps.TIMBER
}
```

**feature_stats/build.gradle**

```
android{
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation AndroidDeps.CONSTRAINT_LAYOUT
    implementation AndroidDeps.NAV_FRAGMENT_KTX
    implementation AndroidDeps.NAV_UI_KTX
    implementation AndroidDeps.MATERIAL_DESIGN

    implementation CustomViewDeps.MP_ANDROID_CHART
}
```